# How to pass an array of IDs as a body in DELETE API?

Tags: arrays, angular, swagger, angular15

My DELETE API on swagger is accepting an array of ids to delete. Like this:

```
[
  42
]
```

I have following code in angular v15. I am not getting how to pass an array of ids as a body to this delete API.

```
deleteProduct(productId: number): Observable<any> {

    let frequencyArray = JSON.parse("[2023]");

    return this.http

      .delete(this.baseUrl + "api/Product/deleteproduct", frequencyArray)

      .pipe(map((data) => data));

  }
```

Above code is giving an error:

> Media type unsupported

I have searched a lot of things, but I am not getting any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the HttpClient class:

```
delete<T>(url: string, options?: {
    headers?: HttpHeaders | {
        [header: string]: string | string[];
    };
    context?: HttpContext;
    observe?: 'body';
    params?: HttpParams | {
        [param: string]: string | number | boolean | ReadonlyArray<string | number | boolean>;
    };
    reportProgress?: boolean;
    responseType?: 'json';
    withCredentials?: boolean;
    body?: any | null;
}): Observable<T>;
```

so you need to pass the body data in the option array.

Example  `.delete(this.baseUrl + "api/Product/deleteproduct", {body: frequencyArray})`

Comment: {body: frequencyArray} Worked, Thanks